# Are there some rules on when you should resign, vs when you stick with it should fight?

Tags: resigning

Are there any hard-fast rules for when you should resign a game or when you should fight for it? For instance, in timed games I've realized if they are destroying me, but running out of time to do it (like, less than 30 seconds) I think it's worth it to make them play it out because it is hard (for lower rated players anyway) to play both accurately and fast.

Are there any well known rules for when you should just give up, or is it mostly up to you whether you think you can win or not?

Comment: Is there a way to merge this question? I think this answer (with borrowed portions from another question) has value not reflected in the other question's current answers.

Comment: Players have the right to play on as long as they wish.

Comment: Yes, but it's sort of a question of proper etiquette/is it useless for me to play this out. I was told it was kind of rude to force someone to checkmate you when you clearly losing. Plus, not resigning wastes both players time if one side will clearly lose anyway.

Comment: I have won and drawn plenty positions that were "clearly lost" due to blunders by the opponent.  If you want to give away points, feel free to resign early to avoid bruising your opponent's ego.

Comment: I've also won several times being a queen down in online blitz games. So it does depend on several factors.

Answer (score 0):

As I was asking this, I came across [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/21387/is-it-wise-to-resign-a-game-if-the-win-is-only-apparent-too-many-moves-ahead), which is not a duplicate of my question, but had some answers which did answer mine, so I decided to answer my own question.

Per [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/21394/18599):

> For beginner players, who tend to blunder a piece or mate in one regularly, there is no point to resign early. Any game, even in (objectively) clearly lost position will help them to gain experience.
>
> For more advanced players, the **decision to resign will depend on various factors and cannot be generalized**.

and

> Some factors to take into account before resigning:
>
> - Do I have any chances for active counterplay?
> - Do I have any chances for drawing (building a fortress, stalemate,...)?
> - Is the position easily won for my opponent or is it rather a "theoretical" win, but difficult to do in "practice"? (e.g.
> - How much time does my opponent
>     have left?
> - Over the last couple of moves, did my opponent show that
>     he understands how to play the position for a win?